# What's the point of Poro-snax in aram map

Tags: league-of-legends

What is the point of the Poro-Snax you get in the map Howling Abyss?

You can consume it when you are close to a "Poro". What will happen? 
Do you get any buffs or regeneration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're actually feeding the nearest Poro when you use it.

There are a few things that happen with Poro-Snax.

- If you have a Poro-Snax in your inventory, Poros will run to you.  This is helpful when you see Poros run into a brush as it tells you an enemy champion is in there.
- If you don't have a Poro-Snax, Poros will run away from you.
- When you use a Poro-Snax on a Poro, it increases in size.  If a Poro is fed enough, it explodes in a shower of normal-sized Poros.

Source: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Poro-Snax

Comment: If Braum feeds a Poro it grows a mustache.

Comment: Yeah I did see the additional effects when playing Braum, but I decided to leave them out since they're specific to one champion.

Comment: I got your back on this one ;)

Comment: Also to note, a non-fed by a champion Poro runs away from the champion, seeing one coming out of a bush tells you a champ is there and forgot to hand over is Poro-Snax... or already had.